Vue2 style in custom-element and in component
When using a component in a vue context and a custom-element context - the styles in the vue context stop working, although they work fine for custom-element, is there a way to make the component styles work in both contexts?
webpack config:
module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.vue$/,
                    loader: 'vue-loader',
                    options: {
                        shadowMode: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/components'),
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'vue-style-loader',
                            options: {
                                shadowMode: true
                            }
                        },
                    ]
                },
            ]
        },

declaration custom element:
import '@webcomponents/custom-elements';
import Vue from "vue";
import wrap from "@vue/web-component-wrapper"
import Element from "../components/Element.vue";

const _Element = wrap(Vue, Element)
window.customElements.define('element-select', _Element);

